# Taking a relative url and forwarding it to a subdomain using jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm wondering if it's possible to take all `<a>` tags inside a div and have them open in a new window which uses a subdomain. Here's what I'm working with:

```
<div id="workshops">
<a href="/_product_119808/Test_Workshop">Test Workshop</a>
</div>
```

I would like to have the Test Workshop link open up in a new window but also use a subdomain. So the link in the new window would be:

> `http://workshops.mydomain.com/_product_119808/Test_Workshop`

Is this possible?? Thanks in advance!

Comment: target="_blank" is not going to do it for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function ()
{
    var domainRoot = "http://workshops.mydomain.com";

    $("#workshops a").each(function ()
    {
        $(this).attr("href", domainRoot + $(this).attr("href"));
        $(this).attr("target", "_blank");
    });
});
```

It would probably be helpful for other people viewing this question if you explained why you needed to use jQuery for this, though, instead of just outputting the links correctly in the first place.

Comment: You might want to cache the jQuery object so you don't create it 3 times.

Comment: Domenic, I need to use jquery because the CMS I'm using only outputs the url as a relative url. It will always default to the main domain and I need to to use a subdomain to enable a different layout for the shopping cart. A hack for sure but the only way I can use a different shopping cart layout in the CMS.

Comment: Thomas, jQuery does that caching for you.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$( '#workshops a' ).each(function(index,item) {
    var $item = $(item);

    $(item)
    .attr('href', "http://workshops.mydomain.com" + $item.attr('href') )
    .attr('target', '_blank');
});
```

I would recommend that you set `target="blank"` via html instead of javascript.